# How do Java Objects get stored in Fields?

Tags: java, object, field

After research on Object fields, all I have found is that [they get stored in that other Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).
But let's say that I'm storing a Class called Inventory on a field at Class A.

```
private Inventory userInventory;
```

That Inventory Object has the criminal record, stored in a hashmap of Crime and Date.

```
private HashMap<Crime, Calendar> record;
```

That map is changed within the Inventory like so:

```
public void addCrime(Crime crime, Calendar instance) {
      record.put(crime, instance);
}
```

My question is, the stored Inventory in the Class A's field will still be the same if I execute addCrime on it?

Comment: Yes. The field is a *reference* to the object, not a copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,Inventory object will be the same,meaning the reference will be the same as before.but its reference object's attr named `record` will add a new pair.

Answer (score 0):

No, map is a datastructure, where you store data as a key value pair, thus with the same key coming in, the value for the existing record would get updated, but if you are using a different key, then existing record would persist.